# Mixed programming: Calling FORTRAN from C

Tags: c, linker, fortran, g77

I have to do a proof of concept on calling FORTRAN subroutines from C/C++.
I don't know what I am in right direction, please guide me....

What I did is...

I wrote the following FORTRAN code

```
INTEGER*4 FUNCTION Fact (n)
INTEGER*4 n
INTEGER*4 i, amt
amt = 1
DO i = 1, n
amt = amt * i
END DO
Fact = amt
END

SUBROUTINE Pythagoras (a, b, c)
REAL*4 a
REAL*4 b
REAL*4 c 
c = SQRT (a * a + b * b)
END
```

compiled it using g77 as `g77.exe -c FORTRANfun.for`

I wrote following c code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int __stdcall FACT (int n);
extern void __stdcall PYTHAGORAS (float a, float b, float *c);

main()
{
    float c;
    printf("Factorial of 7 is: %d\n", FACT(7));
    PYTHAGORAS (30, 40, &c);
    printf("Hypotenuse if sides 30, 40 is: %f\n", c);
}
```

compiled it using Visual Studio C compiler as `cl /c new.c`

When I tried to link, as `LINK new.obj FORTRANfun.o`
I am getting the following error...

```
new.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FACT@4 referenced in function _main
new.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PYTHAGORAS@12 referenced in function _main
new.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: this is probably due to different symbol case. Because case is not preserved, GNU Fortran by default maps all symbols to lower case when compiling. Try `extern int __stdcall fact(int n); ...` to compensate for that.

Comment: I suggest gfortran or another current compiler rather than g77.  gfortran can compile FORTRAN 77 and Fortran >= 90. g77 has not been supported for many years.  Take a look at the Fortran ISO_C_Binding.  Part of Fortran 2003, as part of the language, it provides a way to specify call C from Fortran (or Fortran from C).  There is a tag here on stackoverflow: fortran-iso-c-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of Zeeshan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23669574/2838364), you have to use pointers for passing variables to Fortran:

```
extern int __stdcall fact(int* n);
extern void __stdcall pythagoras(float* a, float* b, float *c);
```

Comment: Excellent!!!... Thanks, was getting crash after Zeeshan answer. Now it is perfectly working fine... Thanks a TON!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's due to symbols case most of the time.

*The f77 comiler flags "-fno-underscore" and "-fno-second-underscore" will alter the default naming in the object code and thus affect linking. One may view the object file with the command nm (i.e.: nm file.o).*

*Note: The case in FORTRAN is NOT preserved and is represented in lower case in the object file. The g77 compiler option "-fsource-case-lower" is default. GNU g77 FORTRAN can be case sensitive with the compile option "-fsource-case-preserve".*

Refer [THIS](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html)

Comment: Very often after doing this one just realizes he can no longer call his numerous Fortran libraries he calls in the code.