# Mixed programming: Calling FORTRAN from C++

Tags: c++, c, dll, fortran

I am trying to compile a mixed program with command line.

Compile tool is intel visual fortran 2013 and VS 2013.

I have googled around and found the using `dll` is easier than `lib`.

So I tried to compile my fortran  source as a dll file

my `Fortran` source:

```
!  forsubs.f90 
!
!  FUNCTIONS/SUBROUTINES exported from FORSUBS.dll:
! FORSUBS      - subroutine 
!
INTEGER*4 FUNCTION Fact (n)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::Fact
      INTEGER*4 n [VALUE]
      INTEGER*4 i, amt
      amt = 1
      DO i = 1, n
        amt = amt * i
      END DO
      Fact = amt
   write(*,*)"Mixed calls succeed!"
END
SUBROUTINE Pythagoras (a, b, c)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::Pythagoras
      REAL*4 a [VALUE]
      REAL*4 b [VALUE]
      REAL*4 c [REFERENCE]
      c = SQRT (a * a + b * b)
END
```

my `C++` source: c_main.cpp

```
/*     File CMAIN.C   */

#include <stdio.h>

extern int __stdcall fact(int* n);
extern void __stdcall pythagoras(float* a, float* b, float *c);

int main()
{
    float c;
    printf("Factorial of 7 is: %d\n", FACT(7));
    PYTHAGORAS (30, 40, &c);
    printf("Hypotenuse if sides 30, 40 is: %f\n", c);
}
```

#### First I compiled my fortran source:

> ifort /dll forsubs.f90

and got a `forsubs.dll` and a `forsubs.lib`.

#### Second I compiled my C++ source:

> cl c_main.cpp /link forsubs.lib

However, I got an error:

```
D:\c_f\c_f_dll\c_main.cpp(11) : error C3861: “FACT”:  identifier not found
D:\c_f\c_f_dll\c_main.cpp(12) : error C3861: “PYTHAGORAS”:  identifier not found
```

Also, I have tried to load dll in another way, by using:

```
 HINSTANCE hLibrary=LoadLibrary("forsubs.dll"); 
 if(hLibrary==NULL)
 {
  cout<<"can't find the dll file"<<endl;
  return -1;
 }
```

But I got an "can't find the dll file" everytime while I am sure the `forsubs.dll` is in the folder.

I am not good at C++ and can not find out how to compile it, help!

### Edit

Strange! I edited my program as @Mikael Persson 's answer, but still got an error.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FACT@4 referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PYTHAGORAS@12 referenced in function _main
```

Also, I googled around and someone said `__stdcall` is not nessary ,I delete but still got error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FACT referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PYTHAGORAS referenced in function _main
```

I thought it may be the same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669364/mixed-programming-calling-fortran-from-c). But can not solve it by myself.

PS:
info of my `dll` and `lib`:

```
D:\c_f\c_f_dll>dumpbin /exports forsubs.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.30501.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file forsubs.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  FACT
                  PYTHAGORAS

  Summary

          C3 .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           8 .idata$4
           8 .idata$5
           C .idata$6

D:\c_f\c_f_dll>dumpbin /exports forsubs.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.30501.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file forsubs.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for forsubs.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5477F1C5 time date stamp Fri Nov 28 11:53:41 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 FACT
          2    1 000010B0 PYTHAGORAS

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text
```

### Edit2

```
Also, I have tried to add a header:
#ifdef FORSUBS_EXPORTS
#define FORSUBS_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define FORSUBS_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

it still not work.

Comment: i don't know about you but the fortran dll file only had functions but didn't have any dllmain switch statement or createthread function. Remember to have correct directory/path for loadlibrary.

Comment: @Amadan, hi,I added `"C"` to code but got the very same error. I thought `__stdcall` is necessary depends on question "Mixed programming: Calling FORTRAN from C". Any idea with the second way in my question?

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong, my apologies. [This](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/mixedProgramming1.pdf) might be a good thing to read, and I should not guess about things I clearly don't know enough about.

Comment: @Bot I put the `dll` in the same directory as `exe`, but still can not find the `dll`.

Comment: I recommend using Fortran's ISO_C_Binding  instead of extensions or previous techniques.  Stackoverflow has a tag on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ is case sensitive, so if you call `FACT`, then it must have been declared as `FACT`, not as `fact`. Or the other way around.

And you need to declare your functions (in the C++ code) as `extern "C"`, to disable to C++-specific name-mangling that would be assumed otherwise.

And `__stdcall` is indeed the correct calling convention for Fortran functions (by default).

Fortran is case-insensitive (by default, but it can be changed via compiler options, which is stupid). I believe that the Intel Fortran compiler generates all-upper-case symbols (for linking purposes) for Fortran functions (e.g., a function named "Fact" will be exported as "FACT"). So, you need to match that case in the C++ declaration. I'm not sure about which way it goes with Fortran symbols (either all-upper-case or all-lower-case), so, if one doesn't work, try the other.

**EDIT 2:**

As for the prototypes, I believe that these are the correct forms in C++ (I'm not sure because I'm pretty rusty when it comes to Fortran):

```
#include <stdint.h>  // in C, or <cstdint> in C++ (but must use std::int32_t)

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int32_t __stdcall FACT(int32_t n);
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall PYTHAGORAS(float a, float b, float *c);
```

Notice that for a 4-byte integer, you need to use `int32_t`, and that for `[VALUE]` types in Fortran, it should also be passed by value in C/C++... at least, that's my understanding of it (but like I said, I'm not a Fortran expert).

Comment: Hi, I edited my code, but got another error, I have updated my question.

Comment: @PaleNeutron Sorry... it's been a while since I've used DLLs, MSVC import libraries, or Windows for that matter.. so I'm a bit rusty with this stuff and don't have anything to test this on. I believe that if you are linking with an import library (the .lib file), then you need to add `__declspec(dllimport)` to the function declarations between `extern "C"` and the return types.

Comment: stdcall is not the default calling convention for the Fortran compiler that the OP is using.